# How can I make this Python code more efficient

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I would greatly appreciate your feedback on my first ever Python project! :D

Basically I am coding a Caesar Cipher and I think its pretty terribly 'optimised / efficient' if you know what I mean, this is because I copied and pasted the encrypt() method for the decrypt() method and the only thing I changes was instead of rotating the numbers more, I rotated them less. This is what I'm talking about:

```
       newPosition = (abc.find(letter) - key) % 26

^^ Instead of having a + (plus) I made it a - (minus) ^^
```

Is there a way I can sort of call the encrypt() method at just the newPosition line? Or what I did was correct and it doesn't need fixing (which I highly doubt)

** Please do take in mind that I do not have much knowledge in Python (if any at all) since I just started today so don't blow my brain up with some super complex code. THANK YOU!!! **

```
abc = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def main():
    message = input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt a word?")
    if message.lower() == "encrypt":
        encrypt()
    elif message.lower() == "decrypt":
        decrypt()
    else:
        print("You must enter either 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'.")
        main()


def encrypt():
    message = input("Enter a message to encrypt: ")
    message = message.lower()
    key = int(input("What number would you like for your key value?"))
    cipherText = ""
    for letter in message:
        if letter in abc:
            newPosition = (abc.find(letter) + key) % 26
            cipherText += abc[newPosition]
        else:
            cipherText += letter
    print(cipherText)
    return cipherText

def decrypt():
    message = input("Enter a message to decrypt: ")
    message = message.lower()
    key = int(input("What number would you like for your key value?"))
    cipherText = ""
    for letter in message:
        if letter in abc:
            newPosition = (abc.find(letter) - key) % 26
            cipherText += abc[newPosition]
        else:
            cipherText += letter
    print(cipherText)
    return cipherText

main()
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a code review. Those go on a [different site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for providing this website!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, `str.find` is bad performance-wise. It's O(n) complexity, which isn't awful, but you rarely actually need it. In this case you can use `ord` to convert each letter to its ordinal, then subtract `ord('a')` to get 0-25 instead of 97-122.

This is particularly useful, because you can then use `chr` to convert back without needing a lookup.

```
for letter in message:
    if letter in string.ascii_lowercase:  # same as "abcdef..z"
        new_position = ((ord(letter) - ord('a') + key) % 26) + ord('a')
        new_ch = chr(new_position)
        ciphertext += new_ch
```

Note also that concatenating strings with `+=` isn't as fast as something like `str.join`.

```
new_letters = [chr(((ord(letter) - ord('a') + key) % 26) + ord('a')) if letter in ascii_lowercase else letter for letter in message]
ciphertext = "".join(new_letters)
```

And since that `chr(((ord(letter) - ord('a') + key) % 26) + ord('a'))` is so ugly, I'd refactor that into a function.

```
def rotate(letter, key=0):
    c_pos = ord(letter) - ord('a')
    rotated = c_pos + key
    modded = rotated % 26
    final_pos = modded + ord('a')
    return chr(final_pos)

new_letters = [rotate(c, key) if c in string.ascii_lowercase else c for c in letters]
ciphertext = "".join(new_letters)
```

---

A point of maintainability: it's easier to write *testably* good code if you separate your inputs from your results. Right now you'd have to do some monkey patching of `stdin` to write unit tests for any of your functions, but if you move your requests for user input into `main` and out of their respective function, that gets much easier.

```
def main():
    message = input("What's the message to encrypt/decrypt? ")
    key = int(input("What number would you like for your key value? "))
    choice = input("Choose: encrypt or decrypt. ")
    if choice == "encrypt":
        result = encrypt(message, key)
    elif choice == "decrypt":
        result = decrypt(message, key)
    else:
        # something here about a bad user input.
```

In fact, when you consider the Caesar Cipher is reversible by flipping the sign of the key, you can simply do:

```
    if choice == "encrypt":
        result = encrypt(message, key)
    elif choice == "decrypt":
        result = encrypt(message, key * (-1))
```

and not write a `decrypt` function at all!

Comment: OMG!! Thank you so much guys!!! I seriously do appreciate you taking your time to help me out!!